# Standardize variables in STATA

Tags: statistics, stata

I was trying to standardize my 100 variables "Apple1, Apple2, Apple3.....". If I did it one by one, it would drive me crazy. I knew `foreach` and `varlist` but I don't know how to use it (even finished reading the manual).

How could I standardize (using standardized value) my 100 variables in Stata in one go?

Comment: I am a little confused what you want.

Comment: The command to standardise 100 variables.

Comment: Finished reading the manual? It's more than 10,000 pages.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, one way to do it is a loop. For variables `Apple1` to `Apple100`,

```
forval j = 1/100 { 
    egen std_Apple`j' = std(Apple`j')
}
```

For any more complicated *varlist*, use `foreach` instead. Say

```
foreach v of varlist <varlist> { 
    egen std_`v' = std(`v')
}
```

where the *varlist* in angle brackets (and also the angle brackets) should be replaced by your list of variables.